# Placeholder URL's with Azure Blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I would like to be able to create a signed URL for a file in the blob store that will exist **eventually**. Currently, with S3, we are able to achieve it as it creates a signed URL without making any assumption of the existence of the file in given S3 location, however in Azure trying to sign a file that doesn't exist is failing.

Use case: Have a batch job which will upload the output eventually to a location in blob storage, however, the UI would need to know the URL upfront so that it can keep polling with `HEAD` requests until the batch job completes.

Comment: Have you considered creating a signed URI to a particular container instead of a specific blob? This would let you create the container *now* and load it *eventually*.

Comment: @DavidMakogon yes I did consider that possibility, however, a HEAD on the container will return `200` because it exists, now would need to make it a little hackier to keep checking for a file inside that container; not exactly the place I want the code to be. We are talking about a lot of files, doesn't feel right to create a container per file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you cannot generate a SAS for a non-existent blob, you *can* generate a SAS for a *placeholder* blob (with whatever placeholder content you choose to place there). If you then replace the blob's contents later (without changing the blob name), the SAS-tokenized URL you originally generated will still be valid, along with the date-range validity you originally configured.

I just confirmed this behavior by uploading a test image to a private container, generating a sas, viewing the image in the browser, uploading a different image (with the same name) to replace the original, refreshing the browser, and seeing the newly-uploaded image.